# Using iptables to map privilaged to non-privilaged port

Tags: apache, iptables, portforwarding

I have an apache webservice running on port 8080 but would like to be able to connect on port 80. However, my unix sysadmin does not allow apache to be started as root nor does she provide access to sudo.

However, she will execute commands on request.

I believe this can be achieved with `iptables`. Is there a way to map port 80 to 8080 and 443 to 8083 without this sysadmin having to edit any files.

i.e. just using `echo` with appender `>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She can do this by running :

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8083
```

This will make redirection active immediately, but doesn't save it and thus it will not work anymore after a reboot.

It is possible to do this without editing any file at all by using `iptables-save`. But it depends which linux flavor you're running, and if you use ferm, ufw, or some other firewall management tools.

On RedHat/CentOS, she could just do :

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8083
iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

On other OSes variants, YMMV !